# space before li items in ol list

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the ol list : before each li item there is a space, I don't need it but I want to keep the number before items.
I tried to deal with it by setting margin and padding to 0 on ol and li elements but it didn't work.
The code looks like this:

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Do you have any idea using only css and html languages?

Comment: check my answer below it works as per your requirement.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. To the user who hasn't made the leap that "space before" might mean "margin/padding"  these are two entirely different questions, and therefore is not a dpulicate of each other. 

It's really about putting yourself in the shoes of other people ask looking at things throough their point of view, and if you do that it's apparent that questions like this are not duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ol and ul list have some margin and padding. It's may gonna fix your problem.
This is what by default ol and ul tag have, [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp)

```
ol {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```css
ol{
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 10px; //by default 40px, it's up to you
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Nice documentation, I like this one

Comment: @DCR Do you ask this question?

Comment: no but your answer doesn't work.  Op clearly states he wants to remove the space between the number and the item => 1. item

Comment: @DCR see my edited ans, is it ok?

Comment: no, but not a bad try.  The padding and margin on the ol  adds margin and padding to the very left, right, top or bottom of the ol.  so it doesn't target the space between the number and the item.  I'm not sure how you can change.  You may have to build a customized ol

Comment: Can you solve this without build a customized ol?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set padding on your ol

```
ol {
    padding-left: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unordered and ordered lists have a default left padding. You can remove that padding by writing a style rule. Like this:

```
ol {
  padding-left:0;
}
```

More info on styling lists [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_lists)

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding on the `ol` element, but keep the list style.

```
ol {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: inside decimal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like.

> It is a cheat code but it works.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: number;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: number;
}
li::before {
  content:counter(number)".";
  position: relative;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ol>
        <li>item</li >
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```